# How to directly access ingress-nginx inside minikube

Tags: nginx, kubernetes

I'm new to K8s and currently following a course that is using K8s.I am using minikube in my local machine. I'm stuck on the part in which I need to directly communicate with ingress-nginx which happens to be in a separate namespace.

Here's some information regarding my setup.

```
    ✗ client (main) ✗ kubectl get namespace
    NAME              STATUS   AGE
    default           Active   25d
    ingress-nginx     Active   21d
    kube-node-lease   Active   25d
    kube-public       Active   25d
    kube-system       Active   25d
```

Service

```
    ✔︎ client (main) ✗ kubectl get services -n ingress-nginx
    NAME                                 TYPE        CLUSTER-IP     EXTERNAL-IP   PORT(S)                      AGE
    ingress-nginx-controller             NodePort    10.105.88.90   <none>        80:30306/TCP,443:31814/TCP   21d
    ingress-nginx-controller-admission   ClusterIP   10.101.75.17   <none>        443/TCP                      21d
```

My ingress-srv.yaml file

```
    apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
    kind: Ingress
    metadata:
      name: ingress-service
      annotations:
        kubernetes.io/ingress.class: nginx
        nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/use-regex: "true"
      labels:
        name: ingress-service
    spec:
      rules:
        - host: ticketing.dev
          http:
            paths:
              - pathType: Prefix
                path: "/api/users/(.*)"
                backend:
                  service:
                    name: auth-srv
                    port:
                      number: 3000
              - pathType: Prefix
                path: /?(.*)
                backend:
                  service:
                    name: client-srv
                    port:
                      number: 3000
```

I looked for some information over [github](https://github.com/kubernetes/ingress-nginx/issues/3665) and to do cross communication what I need to do is doing `http://<service>.<namespace>.svc.cluster.local:<port>/`. Based on that info, I came up with
`http://ingress-nginx-controller.ingress-nginx.svc.cluster.local` and test it using curl.

```
✔︎ client (main) ✗ curl http://ingress-nginx-controller.ingress-nginx.svc.cluster.local
curl: (6) Could not resolve host: ingress-nginx-controller.ingress-nginx.svc.cluster.local
```

I'm following a course called  [Microservices with Node JS and React](https://www.udemy.com/course/microservices-with-node-js-and-react/)

Hope for your answers and insights.
Thank you.

Comment: Why do you need to send calls to the `nginx-ingress-controller service`? It's supposed it should listen to on a domain name where your application is running. Or instead to the `app-service` directly

Comment: Hi, I'm learning k8s through a course of microservices and in it, it mentions it should reach out to ingress-nginx. He suggested the `http://<service>.<namespace>.svc.cluster.local:<port>/my/api/route` so it fix an error in NextJS. This problem is actually related or similar to this existing question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64707777/error-getaddrinfo-enotfound-ingress-nginx-ingress-nginx-controller-svc-cluster but I'm not sure why  I get a different result.

Comment: Where did you run this curl command? If you're running this on your host machine, you won't be able to reach out `internal` kubernetes cluster DNS. You can test its accessibility within the cluster by `kubectl run test --image nginx --attach --leave-stdin-open --rm -it -- curl ingress-nginx-controller.ingress-nginx.svc.cluster.local` -  this will run a pod with `nginx` image and then run `curl` to that `nginx ingress controller` from the inside of the cluster. Then `ctrl-c` and `kubectl logs test`. You'll see the answer.

Answer (score 1):

If you ingress controller in Ingress-nginx namespace it perfect or also fine it's any other namespace.

You have create the ingress object in that namespace where your application running, regardless of where you controller running.

Ingress will find the controller or communicate with it across namespace automatically using the class that you have specified in the **ingress** object.

In simple words

If your **app1** running in namespace **application** just create one **ingress** in **application** namespace pointing to **app1** *service* and you are done.

```
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
    kind: Ingress
    metadata:
      name: ingress-service
      annotations:
        kubernetes.io/ingress.class: nginx
        nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/use-regex: "true"
      labels:
        name: ingress-service
    spec:
      rules:
        - host: ticketing.dev
          http:
            paths:
              - pathType: Prefix
                path: "/api/users/(.*)"
                backend:
                  service:
                    name: auth-srv
                    port:
                      number: 3000
              - pathType: Prefix
                path: /?(.*)
                backend:
                  service:
                    name: client-srv
                    port:
                      number: 3000
```

- Ingress Controller(simple Pod/Deployment along with a Service that can be used to utilize routing and proxying. Based on Nginx example);
- Ingress rules(a separate Kubernetes resource with **kind: Ingress**. Will only take effect if Ingress Controller is already existing and **class** is mentioned in ingress)

Ingress Controller can be deployed in any namespace, usually deployed in a namespace separate from your app services like you have done in **ingress-nginx**. It can out-of-the-box see Ingress rules in all namespaces in the cluster and will pick them up.

The Ingress rules, however, must reside in the namespace where the app that they configure reside.

Comment: Hi, I'm not sure if I get your answer correctly, do you mean I need to change the namespace of my ingress-nginx to default one, since all my other running applications runs under default namespace.

My issue is accessing `http://ingress-nginx-controller.ingress-nginx.svc.cluster.local` which will be used in an API call.